# Routing not working as intendeded

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am looking to have a WebAPI controller "ContractController" that takes a get and a post with a uri such as

```
    (POST)
    http://locolhost:34567/api/v1/Contract

    (GET)
    http://locolhost:34567/api/v1/Contract/1234567890
```

The route I have almost works the way I need:

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          "GetPost",
          "api/v1/Policy/{id}",
          new { controller = "Policy", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

except that if I perform a post in Fiddler: `http://locolhost:34567/api/v1/Contract`
I get a 404.

If I add in anything after 'contract'

```
http://locolhost:34567/api/v1/Contract/Foo
http://locolhost:34567/api/v1/Contract/12



 It works as expected but 

http://locolhost:34567/api/v1/Contract
or
http://locolhost:34567/api/v1/Contract/ 

give a HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.

The controller has only 2 public methods (GetContract & PostContract)
Any thoughts on what I am missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally figured out what the issue was.

My GLobal.asa file had

```
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

The answer was by inverting the order when the routes got registered.

```
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

THis project also helped
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx